# Como llamo una clase que esta fuera(pero en el mismo div)que el elemento $(this) al que estoy llamando en jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

He intentado buscar la forma para hacer un codigo corto para una pagina donde al darle click a un elemento haga que se haga visible otro mediante jquery. El problema esta que necesito que esta acción se repita varias veces dentro de la misma pagina con elementos identicos. Para ello he usado una clase y llamandola con `$(this)` hace que solo ese elemento al que hago click funcione y no los demás aunque estos tengan la misma clase.

Aqui esta mas o menos lo que quiero hacer:

```
            $(this < ".Producto .descripcion").css("visibility", "visible");
```

O algo similar a un find pero que busque fuera del elemento llamado con el `$(this)`

Comment: Quieres que si el elemento padre de tu contenedor tiene la clase `Producto` o la clase `descripcion` te ponga la regla css: `visibility: visible`?, o quieres buscar cualquier elemeto adyacente a ese que tenga esas clases para que esto suceda?

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara. Pulsa en [edit] para completarla. Si es posible pon un ejemplo, basado en HTML/Javascript de lo que quieres lograr.

Comment: Quiero que el elemento con la clase `descripcion`, que esta dentro del contenedor con clase `Producto`, se le ponga la regla `visibility: visible`

Comment: Puedes usar [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) para buscar el padre, algo como `$(this).closest('div.Producto').find('.descripcion')`

Comment: Me funcionó de maravilla. Muchas gracias :DDD @Triby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quiza seria buena idea que para futuras preguntas coloques un poco mas de `HTML` un poco mas de informacion, mas o menos algo parecido a esto:

```
<div class = "Producto">
   <div class = "descripcion">

   </div>
</div>
```

Ya que colocarlo de esta forma:

```
$(this < ".Producto .descripcion").css("visibility", "visible");
```

No es que nos de demasiada informacion tan relevante, es decir, los que saben `css` sabemos que a lo que se refiere es que le atribuya a todos los elementos con clase `descripcion` que esten dentro de un contenedor con la clase `Producto` el estilo:

```
visibility: visible;
```

Sin embargo al no mostrar tu estructura tal cual la tienes puede ser diferente a lo que nosotros pensamos, por ende la respuesta puede no ser precisa o incluso erronea, por este motivo es muy importante que lo que sea `HTML` lo muestres como `HTML`, que lo que sea `CSS` lo muestres como `CSS`, etc.

Muy bien, segun lo que yo te entendi es esto mas o menos lo que quieres realizar:

```js
$(document).ready(()=>{
  
  $(".Producto").click(function(){
    $(this).find("div.descripcion").css("visibility", "visible");
  });
  
});
```

```css
.Producto{
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f00;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "Producto">
  <div class = "descripcion" style = "visibility: hidden;">
    Descripcion de producto 1!
  </div>
</div>

<div class = "Producto">
  <div class = "descripcion" style = "visibility: hidden;">
    Descripcion de producto 2!
  </div>
</div>
```

Esto lo podemos hacer con `find` de `jQuery` la idea como vemos es ponerle el evento oyente al **contenedor** de esta manera nos aseguramos que primero:

- El contenedor tenga la clase que necesitas
- Que dentro del contenedor se encuentre la clase hija que necesitas

**find** lo que hace es buscarte en un elemento `HTML` todos los elementos que coincidan con el selector que buscas, en caso de ser solo 1 te retorna ese.

Luego al tener la lista filtrada de elementos que necesitamos (`"divs que tengan la clase descripcion"`) lo que hacemos es aplicarle el `css` correspondiente:

```
$(this).find("div.descripcion").css("visibility", "visible");
```

De esta manera se ejecutara ese `css` solo para la tarjeta que hayas clickeado.

Comment: Muchas gracias por toda la información, lo tendre muy en cuenta en futuras ocasiones. :)